# Is there a way to create Proguard settings for my Android Application?

Tags: android, android-volley, libraries, android-proguard

I have my android project ready with 6 external libraries, now I want to automatically generate proguard for my application.

Is it possible to generate proguard file along with all libraries included?

Here are my libraries:

1. android-floating-action-button
2. android-support-v7-appcompat
3. cardview
4. google-play-services
5. recyclerview
6. volley

This is my proguard_project.txt file:

```
    -optimizationpasses 1
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

# Comment out the following line, will cause popular "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"
##-dontobfuscate

-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
-dontwarn javax.swing.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.**
-dontwarn java.beans.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.**
-dontwarn com.ibm.icu.text.**
-dontwarn demo.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn android.support.v7.cardview.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.**
-dontwarn com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.**

# Hold onto the mapping.text file, it can be used to unobfuscate stack traces in the developer console using the retrace tool
-printmapping mapping.txt

# Keep line numbers so they appear in the stack trace of the develeper console 
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

# https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/discussion/182456/thread/e4d73acf
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep interface org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.** { *; }

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
  public static int d(...);
  public static int i(...);
  public static int e(...);
  public static int v(...);  
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer{
    <methods>;
}
```

These are my console errors:

```
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth.GoogleOAuthAuthorizeTemporaryTokenUrl: can't find superclass or interface com.google.api.client.auth.oauth.OAuthAuthorizeTemporaryTokenUrl
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth.GoogleOAuthGetAccessToken: can't find superclass or interface com.google.api.client.auth.oauth.OAuthGetAccessToken
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth.GoogleOAuthGetTemporaryToken: can't find superclass or interface com.google.api.client.auth.oauth.OAuthGetTemporaryToken
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow: can't find superclass or interface com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow

    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Charsets
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.BearerToken
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential
   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.CredentialRefreshListener
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.jsontoken.JsonWebSignature$Header
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.jsontoken.JsonWebToken$Payload
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential

    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.BearerToken
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential$Builder
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder: can't find referenced method 'com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential$AccessMethod getMethod()' in program class com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder: can't find referenced method 'com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport getTransport()' in program class com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder

    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessTokenRequest$GoogleRefreshTokenGrant: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest$RefreshTokenGrant
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessTokenRequest$GoogleRefreshTokenGrant: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest$RefreshTokenGrant
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessTokenRequest$GoogleRefreshTokenGrant: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AuthorizationRequestUrl
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AuthorizationRequestUrl

    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.BatchUnparsedResponse: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.MultipartMixedContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.MultipartMixedContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.MultipartMixedContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Strings
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions

    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.xml.atom.AtomPatchRelativeToOriginalContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.AbstractHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Charsets
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.AbstractHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Charsets
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.io.ByteStreams
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.io.ByteStreams
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.BasicAuthentication: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.BasicAuthentication: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.ByteArrayContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.ByteArrayContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.ByteArrayContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.ExponentialBackOffPolicy: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.ExponentialBackOffPolicy: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.FileContent: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.FileContent: can't find referenced class 
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.UrlEncodedParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.io.CharStreams
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.UrlEncodedParser$Builder: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.UrlEncodedParser$Builder: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpClient: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpClient: can't find referenced class 
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpClient$Builder: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpClient$Builder: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions

    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Charsets
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Charsets
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonParser: can't find referenced class 
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser

    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong

    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.XmlNamespaceDictionary: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.XmlNamespaceDictionary: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.XmlNamespaceDictionary: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.XmlObjectParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.XmlObjectParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.XmlObjectParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.atom.AbstractAtomFeedParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.atom.AbstractAtomFeedParser: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.atom.Atom: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.atom.Atom: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.atom.Atom: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.atom.Atom: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Charsets
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.google.api.client.xml.atom.Atom: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Charsets
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class 
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.Args
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.Args
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.Args
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart: can't find referenced class 
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Consts
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.Args
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: there were 774 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] Warning: there were 47 unresolved references to program class members.
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime]          You may need to recompile the code.
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
    [2015-08-07 19:16:31 - RightPlaceRightTime]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:538)
```

Comment: are you using Eclipse or Android Studio ?

Comment: i am using eclipse @kedarnath

Comment: ok then open `project.properties` file and read it. After it open `proguard-project.txt` where you can set the proguard settings.

Comment: i have already created progaurd-project.txt file.but i need help regarding what is the code that i have to paste inside it @kedarnath

Comment: Did you uncomment the line after this line "To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):" in project.properties file ?   Something like this line "#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt"

Comment: yes i did that,but i am getting build errors..if u want i will post my progaurd_project file code

Comment: Yes, please post the it and also post the build errors.

Comment: PLaese check my edited code in main post @kedarnath

Comment: with this code i am not getting any build errors my apk is generated and it is crashed while opening .just now i checked it.

Comment: Then please post the crashed logs, so that we can help you to solve it.

Comment: i am installing it from my pc it cannot create any logs.....it is crashing while changing from one activity to another(i checked using toasts)

Comment: You can check it when your device is attached, or you can run the code in emulator. We can not predict your error logs so can't help you.

Comment: I added my updated proguard-project.txt and my console errors,please check @kedarnath

Comment: @Harikrishna - Have you resolve the above error, because I am getting same error.